# Pass/Receive <list> between pages and fill listview/richtextbox C# Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8

I'm creating a little app to Win. Phone 8.1, that the user select a number of checkboxes, then, the app does a Foreach to verify which checkbox is selected, then the app gets the checkboxes content (text), fills a `<list>` and send the list to another page, and in the page 2, fill a listview control.

Page 1

```
List<ClassDados> lista = new List<ClassDados>();

ClassDados cDados = new ClassDados();
foreach (CheckBox c in checkboxes)
{
    if (c.IsChecked == true)
    {                  
        cDados.Pedido = c.Content.ToString();
        lista.Add(cDados);
    }
}

Frame.Navigate(typeof(Carrinho), (lista));
```

My Class:

```
class ClassDados
{
    public string Pedido { get; set; }
    public int Valor { get; set; }
}
```

Page 2

```
public sealed partial class Carrinho : Page
{
    List<ClassDados> lista = new List<ClassDados>();

    public Carrinho()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ClassDados c = e.Parameter as ClassDados;
        Cardapio car = e.Parameter as Cardapio;

    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ClassDados c = e.Parameter as ClassDados;
        Cardapio car = e.Parameter as Cardapio;

    }
}
```

My point is: receive the data of page 1 and fill listview/richtexbox control with the data of page 1, but I can't do this, because my way to do this is the same on C# Windows Forms, but is different to windows phone, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want to receive an object of type `ClassDados` on **Page 2**, although on **Page 1** you pass a List of ClassDados `List<ClassDados> lista`. So on **Page 2** write `List<ClassDados> lista = e.Parameter as List<ClassDados>`. That should do the trick. Also, make sure you check for null when retrieving object from `e.Parameter`!

Comment: Oh man it hurts, i found my error, there is no list<ClassDados> its only List<String> and List<string> lista = e.Parameter as List<string>

Comment: I dont know who or how list<ClassDados> appeared here, its incorrect, with your sugestion i discovered it. THAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANKS

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question. Do you want to pass the `List<ClassDados>` created on Page 1 to Page 2?

Firstly, move the `ClassDados cDados = new ClassDados();` line into the foreach loop (Page 1):

```
foreach (CheckBox c in checkboxes)
{
    if (c.IsChecked)
    {
        ClassDados cDados = new ClassDados();               
        cDados.Pedido = c.Content.ToString();
        lista.Add(cDados);
    }
}
```

Then add another constructor to Page 2:

```
public Carrinho(List<ClassDados> cDados)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    // Use cDados to populate your control
}
```

I also notice that `ClassDados.Valor` is unused. You could add a constructor to `ClassDados` that accepts a string and populates the `Pedido` property.